# Call function when audio play button is clicked angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, html5-audio

I have this audio player in my component page

```
<audio id="player" controls="controls" class="audiocontrol">
        <source src="{{ baseUrl }}storage/{{this.url}}" />
</audio>
```

and in my `.ts` file i automatically call the `play_audio` function to play the audio when page loads. This Section is working.

```
 play_audio()
    {  
      ​​try { 
      var player = <HTMLAudioElement> document.querySelector('#player');
      player.load();
      var promise = player.play();
      ..
      player.addEventListener("ended", (currentTime)=>{

      });
    }
```

but i want to call function of angular when i click on play button manually on audio control.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Did you [read the doc](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) ?

Comment: @temp_user Yes i checked, i want to call custom function when clicked on play button of audio control in angular

Comment: Then please read it again. You have event listeners made for that.

Comment: @temp_user Yes there are event listeners like `play` and `stop` that i'm already using but it is inside `play_audio` function but how will i bind these events with methods i don't have much idea of angular

Comment: You are literally already doing it with "ended". Just do the same for pause and play ?

Comment: @temp_user : I tried this code  `player.addEventListener("play", (currentTime) => {
    console.log('play---');    });` but it is not working may be it is within `play_audio` method that's why not getting called `play_Audio` is called on `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer implementation from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_play)

Method 1:
By using normal button click

Method 2:
By using addEventListener()

I hope this solution will worked